# Keycloak server problem Could not find or load main class

Tags: java, cmd, keycloak, keycloak-connect

I can't run keycloak server, when I try to run kc.bat in windows powershell or cmd with

```
.\kc.bat
```

I get the error

```
Error: Could not find or load main class io.quarkus.bootstrap.runner.QuarkusEntryPoint
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.quarkus.bootstrap.runner.QuarkusEntryPoint
```

I installed quarkus but it doesn't work even tho I installed it

Comment: @JishnuPrathap it doesnt' show anything, but when I open windows power shell and type `quarkus --version` then it shows that I have 2.13.3.Final

Comment: There is an open bug https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/issues/15281 related to this

Comment: Thank you, now I will know where to look when I will get stack

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is an [open bug](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/issues/15281) related to this issue.

You have to edit `kc.bat` [line 127](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/9f95b6ec63489f70df98617ece794e1ce2c9f0df/quarkus/dist/src/main/content/bin/kc.bat#L127) replace `:` with `;`

Comment: set "CLASSPATH_OPTS=%DIRNAME%..\lib\quarkus-run.jar;%DIRNAME%..\lib\bootstrap\*"   - this is right row.

Comment: Can also mean that the `lib` folder is missing , or not present in correct path `..\\` (i.e., one level above - parallel to the bin folder)